# Why does this Powershell command always result in a different file encoding?

Tags: windows, powershell, encoding, windows-7, ucs2

If `file1.txt` is encoded in ANSI, and this command is run:

```
powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File file2.txt"
```

then `file2.txt` is always encoded in UCS-2 LE BOM.

Why, and how can I specify the output to be ANSI encoded?

Answer (score 3):

You could also go ahead and use `Set-Content`. This seems to keep the encoding in the file, so you dont have to worry about, what enconding might be correct.

```
powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Set-Content file2.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-enconding Ascii` to ensure the output file is ASCII.

The command will be:

powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File -Encoding Ascii file2.txt"